# Transforming the response on regression

Tags: regression

i wanted to make two similar questions :

1) if i have a model : logy=b0+b1*x and b1 is statistically significant different of 0 , can we assume that in the model y=b0+b1*x will also be statistically significant diferrent to 0?

2)If i seek whether there is a difference between y and x ,and i have a model like the above : logy=b0+b1*x ,then i can only speak about the logarithmic relationship between y and x?

Comment: 1) No, you can't
2) Yes

Answer (score 1):

1) Here's a counter-example:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,3)
y = c(1,4,5,4.5,4.5,4,3.8,1,3.5,2.5,2.5)
lny = log(y)
anova(lm(y~x))
anova(lm(lny~x))
```

p = 0.05461 for y and p = 0.03907 for log y.

2) Assume you mean relationship and not difference, yes. In fact it's quite common to do this.

Comment: What if log(Y|x) ~ Normal ? For example log(Y)=b0+b1*X , X=0 or1 , i want to test if b1=0 vs b1 =! 0 . Then i think that whatever i find for the model of logY i can say it for the model of Y because :

Comment: b1=E[log(Y|X=1)] - E[log(Y|X=0)] = 0 (under the null hypothesis) <=> 
log[E(Y|x=1)] - log[E(Y|X=0)]=0   (because of the symmetry of the distribution and the monotonus function log)  <=> E(Y|x=1)= E(Y|x=0)